# How to update column with ascending value column

Tags: postgresql

I would like to add an **order** column wich will be position of my record. Positions are connected with name. If the name is S1 - order should be 1, for S2 - order should equal 2 etc. How can I do this?

Real state:

```
id       name     position
-------  -------  -------
1        S4       null
2        S2       null
3        S3       null
4        S1       null
```

Expected:

```
id       name     position
-------  -------  -------
1        S4       4
2        S2       2
3        S3       3
4        S1       1
```

I tried with update:

```
WITH x AS
(
  SELECT
      id,
      name,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY name) position
  FROM
      stage
)
UPDATE
    stage
SET
    position = x.position
FROM
    x
WHERE
    x.id = stage.id;
```

Stage is the name of the table.

Comment: Should order be the number in name, or the relative position among names? I.e. for name S1, S2, S5, would order be 1,2,3 or 1,2,5?

Comment: Yes, an order should relative to name. If S1 - order 1, if S2 - order 2

Comment: In my example, S1, S2, S5, what would order be?

Comment: Should be 1, 2 and 5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [ROW_NUMBER()](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-row_number/) window function:

```
WITH x AS
(
  SELECT
      id,
      name,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY name) ord
  FROM
      tbl
)
UPDATE
    tbl
SET
    ord = x.ord
FROM
    x
WHERE
    x.id = tbl.id;
```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM tbl;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | name | ord
> -: | :--- | --:
>  1 | S4   |   4
>  2 | S2   |   2
>  3 | S3   |   3
>  4 | S1   |   1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=86eccff88683f20a11ae8ac49e803bff)*

If there isn't duplicated names you can remove 'S' from name:

```
UPDATE
    tbl
SET
    position = right(name, length(name) - 1)::int
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=4ac825d2122d353b4c44a86838ada95f)*

Comment: Position can not be same. How to avoid adding records with same position?

Comment: Please update your question by adding a real example of your data and the expected result.

Comment: @Bob, row_number() will never repeat the same number per partition (there's only one partition here)

Comment: I added real state and expected one. Your select doesn't update my table. I need to use sequence I guess to update orders number and avoid adding another record with same position.

Comment: @McNets I had an error `ERROR: syntax error in or close "FROM"
LINE 7:   FROM
          ^


SQL state: 42601
Character: 92` I change table name.

Comment: You're using a reserved word 'order', you should double-quote it. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=edcbcf545558afb480d91eac8dca6dd9

Comment: I changed order to position before but still has same error - now it is next to "position"

Comment: Add your current update sentence to the question.

Comment: @McNets I added it

Comment: @McNets how can I set the column **position** to **auto-increment**? I used **serial** data type however I've got error from Java that the position can not be null.

Comment: Please add a new question to the site, and paste the link here. You can add a reference to this question in your new one.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is everything after the letter S, something like:

```
update tbl 
    set ord = substr(name,2)::int;
```

should do. Question is why you have to have a column for this, can't you just order by:

```
select * from tbl order by substr(name,2)::int;
```

It is good practice to not duplicate data unless there's a good reason for it.

Comment: I have simple names now but it is going to change in the future so I need position column to show what was first, second, third etc..